# как разыменовать двойной указатель на класс

Tags: c++, sfml

есть указатель на массив объектов s и указатель на s

```
pngg *s = new pngg[amo];
pngg  **ss=&s;
```

класс pngg:

```
class pngg
{
public:

Texture texture;
Sprite sprite;
int enum_value;
pngg(){}; 
pngg(string way)
{
    texture.loadFromFile(way);
    sprite.setTexture(texture);

}
};
```

как достать Sprite из указателя на указатель?
так не работает:

```
window.draw(*ss->sprite);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*ss->sprite
```

будет интерпрерироваться как
  `*(ss->sprite)`
, 
так как приоритет оператора `->` выше, поэтому нужно написать

```
(*ss)->sprite
```